# PHP script to extract zip on whm server

Tags: php, zip, cpanel, unzip, whm

I am creating a script that creates a subdomain on a whm server and then uploads a zip through ftp to it. That part is working fine and my newly created subdomain functions properly and the file I want gets transfered to it.

**All I need is to unzip this file.** One can easily do it using cpanel's built in file manager but I need this done in my own script. Is there some way to **invoke** cpanel's zip **extraction** functionality **from my script**?

Using PHP's ZipArchive is a problem because it's open() and extractTo() functions **cannot take url** as argument and the zip file I am talking about is not located in a place that I can access without a url. Here's why:

While I am logged in with cpanel_user_1 I created a subdomain that belongs to it's newly created user (let's say cpanel_user_2). I cannot just open the files in cpanel_user_2's public_html folder because that's the way cpanel works - I don't have access to another cpanel user's files. If ZipArhive could work with url I would just do:

```
        $zip = new ZipArchive;
        $zip->open('http://subdomain.domain.com/some_zip.zip')
        $zip->extractTo('http://subdomain.domain.com/folder/some_zip.zip');
        $zip->close();
```

But it doesn't... and I don't have access to the actual file path of the file.

Comment: If you just need to unzip a file, can't you just use PHP's built in [ZipArchive](http://php.net/ZipArchive)?

Comment: Haven't used it before. Can you give me a simple example of how it can be invoked? I have a .zip file that needs unzipping - if you can copy the code needed for that zip to get extracted you would save me a lot of researching and time.

Comment: Just give [this](http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.extractto.php) a read, it has examples on doing exactly that.

Comment: Took a look and got how it works but there is a problem. As I said I created a subdomain and then copy the zip to it so I can't just open the zip file from the other domain remotely and extract it remotely (at least I didn't find a way to do that).

Simply put I am using 1 cpanel user that has access to /home/cpanel_user_1/public_html but want to unzip an archive that is located in another cpanel user's directory - /home/cpanel_user_2/public_html. I can't open the file or extract it remotely (ot at least didn't find a way to do so)